# Nuanced meaning of 実際、いまこうやって目の前にするまでは

Tags: meaning, nuances

> 例年ありますからね。『まあ、もらえるんだろうな』とは思ってましたけど、実際、いまこうやって目の前にするまでは、この権利証があるのかどうか、よくわからなかったですし。

In the context the speaker is recieving a contract (let's say a job contract). In this particular scene he is sitting on a chair with the contract laying in front of him on a table, he is acting very cocky because he won a similar contract years ago but was cheated out the job, so he is trying to remind that to the company.

> 実際、いまこうやって目の前にするまでは

Is this sentence implying that the speaker wasn't expecting to see the contract laying in front of him, or is it implying that he was expecting it and it was the only way to know he'd be getting the contract.
Also, I'm not sure whether いま is connected to こうやって or to まで.

Comment: This sentence sounds paradoxical. I am not so sure though, My initial attempt: "実際、いまこうやって目の前にするまでは"  In fact, up until now the time has come in a way seeing the contract just in front of me, I have not been so sure...

Comment: Does it make sense?

Comment: @kimiTanaka not really, but why do you say it sounds paradoxical?

Comment: Because he feels that he can get the contract every year, but he was not so sure at that moment the contract laying in front of him. Anyway, I'll think about that again. Hope someone else explains clearly.

Comment: @kimiTanaka  例年ありますからね this line is referencing to the fact that the company hands these contracts every year to the winners of a tournament held every year,

Comment: Is it that strange to expect something while not being so sure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He has inferred there should be the contract as same as previous years' winners. But he was cheated out of the job contract before. Therefore, in his case, the very moment he is seeing the contract just in front of him, he has not been so sure if he could expect the contract will exist in the world or not.